# How to route vpn traffic over hostapd-raspberry pi

Tags: linux, iptables, raspberry-pi, vpn

I have a raspberry pi running hostapd and I am able to connect my laptop as a wifi client to the raspberry bi wifi router.
The problem is with the VPN traffic; I can't connect to my office VPN with raspberry pi router.

My iptables are

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1277 packets, 80265 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 328 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1862K 2369M ACCEPT     all  --  ppp0   wlan0   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 729K  152M ACCEPT     all  --  wlan0  ppp0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1069 packets, 167K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: google "hostapd iptables masquerade" to find how to setup NAT on you RPI